# How does one create a color wheel in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, svg, color-spaces

How does one go about creating a VHS color picker shown below? I know it has to be a gradient around a circle, but then toward the center it gets lighter. The center is white.

[image]

P.S. I have looked at this previous question about it, but it is not the same:

[How to draw a color wheel in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74525/how-to-draw-a-color-wheel-in-illustrator)

Comment: How is this question any different than the previous question? They appear to be identical to me.

Comment: @Scott After initially marking it as a duplicate I realized what was different. The white spot at the center...Another circle with a radial gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...but then toward the center it gets lighter. The center is white"

It's the same thing as in the question/answer from your link. The only different thing about them is that white spot at the center.

So, follow all the steps from [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/74527/48529) (The one from your link).

And after that, create another circle on top and apply a white radial gradient from white > 100% Opacity to white > 0% Opacity then adjust to your needs.

[image]

> The dark circle from my example is where the result from the linked
>   answer goes.

Comment: Is there a way to do it on one step, instead of creating two gradients?

Comment: @Dolan It's easy enough as it is. You will always have to combine shapes and techniques to achieve different things. This is the fastest and easiest way.

Comment: @Dolan this could be done with a gradient mesh, but it's much simpler to add the second gradient.